# ClickOnce Application Not Opening

Tags: vb.net, clickonce

I have a VB.NET ClickOnce application that I am trying to install on my computer.  Previously, I was able to install and run these apps without issue.  Now when I install the application, I can see the flash of a window opening, and then nothing. (There are also no processes left hanging or anything when viewed with the task manager.)

After some digging around I noticed that there are files in my Temporary Internet Files with names like "FusionBindError" and then my application name and different DLL names.

I have done everything I can find on the net to do, reinstall applications, reinstalled the .NET Framework, deleted my Local Settings folder and relogged in.

Does anyone out there have any other ideas for me to try?

I tried the Mage.exe suggestion, but it failed to help. Same with the other installation location suggestion.  The application flashes at the bottom of the screen but does not open.  I have tried using FUSLOGVW to check the bindings and nothing shows up in there. (Good or bad, there are no binding entries.)

Comment: any errors logged in event log?

Comment: Nothing in the event viewer that is directly related to my application.

Comment: Try logging on your first line of code. See if it's even getting to your stuff or failing earlier.

Comment: I have the app throwing up a message box on load, and I don't even see that.  I have about 5 ClickOnce apps, and they all do pretty much the same thing when I open them.  A flash on the screen, and gone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I uninstalled my Kensington Mouse software, and that resolved my installation errors.

Who knew that mouse software that I never used could cause so much trouble??

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using mage.exe?  This is a command-line tool that comes with .NET framework.  Start up a VS command prompt, and try mage -cc.  This will clear your applicaiton cache and will force a new click-once download.  This is the first thing I do when my click-once applications fail and it works 99% of the time.

Answer (score 1):

A couple of suggestions:

FusLogVW isn't working for you because you have to enable assembly binding failure logging inside the registry. This [MSDN article describes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e74a18c4(VS.71).aspx) how to do this.

Another thing that comes to mind is, perhaps the ClickOnce app install, or perhaps the whole ClickOnce store is corrupted. Try deleting the ClickOnce app store then reinstalling the application.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that new prerequisites were added that you don't have on hand. If the URL you are using points directly to "my.application" or whatever your equivalent is, prerequisites won't be processed.

So try pointing to the setup.exe that is created in the same directory as the .application file.

Other than that, it sounds like you're doing all the right stuff...

Answer (score 0):

Also, it could be useful to run the fuslogvw utility on a machine where the application actually works. Or reflector.

And then see if indeed any of its dependencies being loaded surprise you.

Also, for these types of errors, be sure to check if disabling the antivirus resident protection helps. Sometimes it causes problems accessing assemblies' manifests and such.

Comment: The applications run just fine on all other machines I have tried them on.  I am thinking that formatting the machine may be the only fix for this issue, but I was really hoping to find a solution for it in case users in our production environment ever have the same problems.

Comment: But have you studied the fuslogvw log in an environment where the applications works?
Also, does reflector say anything?

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes if your machine is working for days this problem will show up. Try to restart your machine. The same problem happened to me and it disappeared when I restarted my machine.